# In Python, I can't get all the return values but the last, what mistake did I do here?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, return

This is my code. I'm trying to take an input from the user, put it in a list, then check every elements if it is less than 5 characters.

It's supposed to print all the names under such condition but it only returns the last element that fits the condition.

My code:

```
#function to check the length of the characters
def test(names):
for x in names:
    if len(x) <= 5:
        print(x)
return x

#ask input from the user 
names = input("Enter names: ").split()

#convert to a list
lst = list(names)

#container 
viewList = test(names)

#print names under 5 characters
print("Names under five characters: ", viewList)

#just to test the elements in the list
print(names)
```

The Output:

```
Enter names: kent monique jeff ban
kent
jeff
ban
Names under five characters:  ban
['kent', 'monique', 'jeff', 'ban']
```

As you can see, it only prints the last element. What mistake am I doing here?

Comment: Your indentation is messed up for a start. You should probably fix that so we all know for sure what you're actual code is.

Comment: Either `yield` it from `test()` or return a list. At the moment, you are returning `x` from after the loop which is then the last element (or `None` if the input was empty).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
#function to check the length of the characters
    def test(names):
        a = []
        for x in names:
            if len(x) <= 5:
                print(x)
                a.append(x)
        return a
    
    #ask input from the user 
    names`enter code here` = input("Enter names: ").split()
    
    #convert to a list
    lst = list(names)
    
    #container 
    viewList = test(names)
    
    #print names under 5 characters
    print("Names under five characters: ", viewList)
    
    #just to test the elements in the list
    print(names)
```

Comment: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." [How-do-I-write-good-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator instead you could use:

```
# function to check the length of the characters
def test(names):
    for x in names:
        if len(x) <= 5:
            yield x


# ask input from the user
names = input("Enter names: ").split()

# container
viewList = [name for name in test(names)]

# print names under 5 characters
print("Names under five characters: ", viewList)

# just to test the elements in the list
print(names)
```

Note that after using `split()` your result is already a list, so converting it to a list is redundant.

---

An often used method is `filter(...)` as in

```
viewList = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 5, names))
```